# Haskell Gloss: random starfield not random?

Tags: haskell, random, particles, gloss

Using Haskell’s Gloss library, I’m trying to simulate a starfield. The visual aspect (drawing ‘stars’ with various speeds and sizes to the screen) is working. However, for some reason the stars aren’t being randomly distributed, resulting in a simulation which has a pattern. I also have this problem with an explosion simulation, but for simplicity’s sake, I’ll leave that one out for now. This is a simplified version of my code so far:

```
type Position       = (Float, Float)
type Velocity       = (Float, Float)
type Size           = Float
type Speed          = Float
type Drag           = Float
type Life           = Int

type Particle       = (Position, Velocity, Speed, Drag, Life, Size)

-- timeHandler is called every frame by the gloss ‘Play’ function. It's being passed
-- the delta time and the world it needs to update.
timeHandler dt world = world {rndGen = mkStdGen (timer world),
                              timer  = (timer world) + 1,
                              stars  = spawnParticle world (rndGen world) : updateParticles (stars world) dt world}

randomFloat :: StdGen -> Float -> Float -> Float
randomFloat rand min max = fst $ randomR (min, max) rand

spawnParticle :: World -> StdGen -> Particle
spawnParticle world gen = ((pos, (1 * speed, 0), speed, 1, 0, size), snd (split gen))
where pos   = (px', py')
      px'   = randomFloat gen (-600) (-500)
      py'   = randomFloat gen (-250) 250
      speed = size * (randomFloat gen 100 300) -- the smaller a particle, the slower 
      size  = randomFloat gen 0.1 1.3

updateParticles :: [Particle] -> Float -> World -> [Particle]
updateParticles []     _  _     = []
updateParticles (x:xs) dt world | fst(posPart x) > 500 = updateParticles xs dt world
                                | otherwise            = updatedPart : updateParticles xs dt world
    where pos'        = updateParticlePosition dt x world
          updatedPart = (pos', velPart x, speedPart x, 1, 0, sizePart x)
```

Note: `velPart`, `speedPart` etc. are functions to get a property out of a given particle. Again, drawing works fine, so I’ll leave that code out. `updateParticlePosition` simply adds the velocity to the current position of a star.

I think the problem has something to do with the fact that my random generators are not passed properly, but I’m too confused to come up with a solution… Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Remember that all Haskell functions are *pure*. With this in mind, how can `randomFloat :: StdGen -> Float -> Float -> Float` be expected to give different results from call to call?

Comment: I thought it should give different results if it's being passed a unique generator every call. At least, that's what Im trying to do..

Comment: You discard the new generator state by discarding the second half of the value returned from `randomR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with gloss, just with the semantics of pure random number generation. Re-initializing a new generator with a new seed every time does *not* give you pseudo-random numbers, because the randomness only comes from the fact that the *new generator* created by e.g. `randomR` or `split` will have seeds very different from the original. You simply have `map mkStdGen [0..]`, as you are simply adding `1` to `timer` at each step.

Consider the difference in the following distributions:

```
map (fst . randomR (1,1000) . mkStdGen) [0..1000]
take 1000 $ randomRs (1,1000) (mkStdGen 123)
```

The first is what you are doing, and the second is proper random numbers.

The solution is simple, just use `split` inside your time update function (you already have it inside of `spawnParticle`) :

```
timeHandler dt world = 
  let (newRndGen, g) = split (rndGen world) in 
   world { rndGen = newRndGen 
         , timer  = (timer world) + 1 , 
         , stars  = spawnParticle world g : updateParticles (stars world) dt world
         }
```

Note that now `timer` isn't used, and it probably makes more sense to have `timer = timer world + dt` anyways (the time deltas may not be exactly equal).

Also keep in mind you shouldn't reuse generators, so if you have many local functions which take a generator as a parameter, you may want something like:

```
timeHandler dt world = 
  let (newRndGen:g0:g1:g2:_) = unfoldr (Just . split) (rndGen world) in 
   world { rndGen = newRndGen 
         , timer  = (timer world) + 1 , 
         , stars  = spawnParticle world g0 : updateParticles (stars world) dt world
         , stuff0 = randomStuff0 g1 , stuff1 = randomStuff1 g2 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It makes sense, however, the starfield is still not random. Remarkably, there is a decrease in particle size / speed, from the top of the screen to the bottom... Is this because I'm reusing `gen` in my `spawnParticle` function?

Comment: I should've tried it first before asking: I applied the same technique in `spawnParticle` as you used in `timeHandler` and it's working now!